# Having issue to store stripe payment details in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

I am integrating Stripe payment in Laravel 5.1 for the first time and I am referring this tutorial [Simple Payments with Stripe and Laravel](http://felicianoprochera.com/simple-payments-with-stripe-and-laravel/) and completed all the steps.

After payment, I am getting this error:

[image]

In stripe logs, its show me the payment done successfully.

I am getting this error in this function:

```
public function createStripeCustomer($token)
{
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));

    $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
        "description" => Auth::user()->email, <-- Error at this line
        "source" => $token
    ));

    //Auth::user()->stripe_id = $customer->id;
    Auth::user()->save();

    return $customer;
}
```

I have created bellow schema for the user but don't understand which details need to store:

```
Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
    $table->string('stripe_id')->nullable();
    $table->string('card_brand')->nullable();
    $table->string('card_last_four')->nullable();
    $table->timestamp('trial_ends_at')->nullable();
});
```

Comment: Because you have not authorized user, and Auth::user() return false, login and try again.

Comment: @VaheGalstyan I am trying as you explained me but can you please tell me which details I have to store in this fields: `stripe_id, card_brand, card_last_four, trial_ends_at`.

Comment: Use tutorial, I added in answers.

Answer (score 0):

Protect your Route using Auth middleware:

```
Route::get('stripepayment', [
    'middleware' => 'auth',
    'uses' => 'OrderController@savePayment'
]);
```

it will automatically check for Auth::user() and redirect you to login page if by chance you logout.

your code gives error because it fails to get Auth::user() because you are not logged-in.

Comment: I am trying as you explained me but can you please tell me which details I have to store in this fields: `stripe_id, card_brand, card_last_four, trial_ends_at`.

Comment: @Mr.Happy in stripe_id you need to store $customer->id , card_brand is one which is selected by user, fetch last 4 char from entered card number for card_last_four And trial_ends_at is expiry date of Card